# Run executable files without the exclamation mark in IPython?

Tags: shell, ipython, executable

Users can run any shell command by prefixing an exclamation mark (`!`) to the shell command in IPython. Or users can run the magic `%rehashx` so that any executables on search path can be used directly. However, there is one annoying situation. If you have an executable that is not on the search path, say, there is an executable Python script `cmder.py` in the currently working directly (which is not on the search path), you still have to `!./cmder.py` or `!/absolute/path/to/cmder.py` to run it. I wonder is there anyway to make IPython recognize `./cmder.py` and `/absolute/path/to/cmder.py` as shell commands?

Comment: I'm generally leery of magic like this. I'd rather go in the opposite direction and get used to putting `!` in front of _all_ shell commands, including ones in my path. The `%rehashx` behavior could come back to bite you later if you try to run a command that happens to match the name of a Python object. On the other hand, the behavior you suggest is unambiguous, since the commands always start with a path specification. I'm guessing you'd have to submit a feature request or add it to Jupyter yourself and submit a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

To run any python script from a shell is as below:

```
python /absolute/path/to/cmder.py
```

Example:

```
bash-3.2$ echo "print('Hello User...')" > shell_python.py
bash-3.2$ cat shell_python.py
print('Hello User...')
bash-3.2$ python shell_python.py
Hello User...
bash-3.2$
```

So to execute the same, use

```
!python /absolute/path/to/cmder.py
```